# When the router shows the same SINR parameter at two different times, but the internet quality is weak , which router parameter should I check?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

When in two different times, the router shows the same SINR parameter, but the internet quality is weaker in one of these two times, so that the browser cannot load the sites, which parameter should I check to check the internet condition?

Comment: You need to look at all the router stats. What is the make and model of your router?

Comment: It’s not necessarily the next link (DSL, Cable or whatever) that is bad. It could literally be anything between you and the traffic destination.

Comment: @DavidPostill - router model : greenpacket GP-2101

Comment: @Daniel - The poor internet situation for me is probably due to problems in the ISP equipment

Comment: So have you spoken to your ISP?

Comment: If you want to collect further "evidence", I recommend something like Smokeping to track latency and packet loss over time.